# Destination tag in RippleApi send transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, payment, send, ripple

**How can I use the destination tag in the Rippleapi payment JSON string**

```
const payment = {
  source: {
    address: ADDRESS_1,
    maxAmount: {
      value: amount,
      currency: currency
    }
  },
  destination: {
    address: ADDRESS_2,
    amount: {
      value: amount,
      currency: currency
    }
  }
}
```

The payment section includes source and destination information about the sender and receiver such as address, amount, currency and so more optional parameters, in the new version of ripple document there is some solution for handle this problem(using destination tag), but i just want to handle my old script and no more changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the docs have changed indeed.
But I suspect you're looking at the transaction history? if so it would look like something like this:

```
const payment = {
  source: {...},
  destination: {
    ...
    "tag": 12341234
  }
}
```

But if you were to build a payment transaction. it would look like the following:

```
{
    "TransactionType" : "Payment",
    "Account" : "rf1BiGeXwwQoi8Z2ueFYTEXSwuJYfV2Jpn",
    "Destination" : "ra5nK24KXen9AHvsdFTKHSANinZseWnPcX",
    "DestinationTag" : 12341234,
    "Amount" : {
        "currency" : "USD",
        "value" : "1",
        "issuer" : "rf1BiGeXwwQoi8Z2ueFYTEXSwuJYfV2Jpn"
    },
    "Fee": "12",
    "Flags": 2147483648,
    "Sequence": 2,
}
```